# Cannot call function in call back for onRequest()

Tags: i2c, arduino-micro

I am a NOOB!  Trying to use the ZS-042 RTC module to retrieve the current time and send it back to the RPi over I2C.  I can call the function and spool it to Serial but when I try to call the function to update the global variables from within the call back function for onRequest() the Ardiuno (Micro) crashes.

```
#include <Wire.h>

// LED on pin 13
const int TEMP_PIN1 = A0;
const int RELAY_PIN1 = 4;
const int SAMPLE_TIME = 100;
const byte RPI_I2C_ADDRESS = 0x08;
const int DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS = 0x68;

byte number = 0;
byte second, minute, hour, dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, month, year;

/*
 * RTC Setup
 */
// Convert normal decimal numbers to binary coded decimal
byte decToBcd(byte val)
{
  return( (val/10*16) + (val%10) );
}
// Convert binary coded decimal to normal decimal numbers
byte bcdToDec(byte val)
{
  return( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );
}
void setDS3231time(byte second, byte minute, byte hour, byte dayOfWeek, byte
      dayOfMonth, byte month, byte year)
{
  // sets time and date data to DS3231
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0); // set next input to start at the seconds register
  Wire.write(decToBcd(second)); // set seconds
  Wire.write(decToBcd(minute)); // set minutes
  Wire.write(decToBcd(hour)); // set hours
  Wire.write(decToBcd(dayOfWeek)); // set day of week (0=Sunday, 6=Saturday)
  Wire.write(decToBcd(dayOfMonth)); // set date (1 to 31)
  Wire.write(decToBcd(month)); // set month
  Wire.write(decToBcd(year)); // set year (0 to 99)
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

/*
void readDS3231time(byte *second,
    byte *minute,
    byte *hour,
    byte *dayOfWeek,
    byte *dayOfMonth,
    byte *month,
    byte *year)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0); // set DS3231 register pointer to 00h
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS, 7);
  // request seven bytes of data from DS3231 starting from register 00h
  *second = bcdToDec(Wire.read() & 0x7f);
  *minute = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  *hour = bcdToDec(Wire.read() & 0x3f);
  *dayOfWeek = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  *dayOfMonth = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  *month = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  *year = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
}
*/

void readDS3231time()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0); // set DS3231 register pointer to 00h
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS, 7);
  // request seven bytes of data from DS3231 starting from register 00h
  second = bcdToDec(Wire.read() & 0x7f);
  minute = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  hour = bcdToDec(Wire.read() & 0x3f);
  dayOfWeek = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  dayOfMonth = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  month = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  year = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
}


void displayTime()
{
  //byte second, minute, hour, dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, month, year;
  // retrieve data from DS3231
  //readDS3231time(&second, &minute, &hour, &dayOfWeek, &dayOfMonth, &month, &year);
  readDS3231time();
  // send it to the serial monitor
  Serial.print(hour, DEC);
  // convert the byte variable to a decimal number when displayed
  Serial.print(":");
  if (minute<10)
  {
    Serial.print("0");
  }
  Serial.print(minute, DEC);
  Serial.print(":");
  if (second<10)
  {
    Serial.print("0");
  }
  Serial.print(second, DEC);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(dayOfMonth, DEC);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(month, DEC);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(year, DEC);
  Serial.print(" Day of week: ");
  switch(dayOfWeek){
  case 0:
    Serial.println("Sunday");
    break;
  case 1:
    Serial.println("Monday");
    break;
  case 2:
    Serial.println("Tuesday");
    break;
  case 3:
    Serial.println("Wednesday");
    break;
  case 4:
    Serial.println("Thursday");
    break;
  case 5:
    Serial.println("Friday");
    break;
  case 6:
    Serial.println("Saturday");
    break;
  }
}


void flash_data(int loops)
{ 
   for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
   {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      Serial.println("LED Pin HIGH: "+String(digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN)));
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
      Serial.println("LED Pin LOW: "+String(digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN)));
      delay(50);
   }
}

// callback for received data
void receiveData(int byteCount)
{
  Serial.println("Receiving Data... ");
  if ( Wire.available() ) {
    number = Wire.read();
  }
  Serial.println("Data Received: "+String(number));
}

void sendData() {
  Serial.println("Sending Data on Request");
  //byte second, minute, hour, dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, month, year;
  // retrieve data from DS3231
  //readDS3231time(&second, &minute, &hour, &dayOfWeek, &dayOfMonth, &month, &year);
  readDS3231time();
  //char buf1[20];
  //sprintf(buf1, "%02d:%02d:%02d %02d/%02d/%02d",  hour, minute, second, dayOfMonth, month, year);
  //Serial.print(buf1);
  Wire.write("Hello");  
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  do {
    delay(500);
  } while (!Serial);

  delay(500);
  Serial.println("Initializing Wire I2C on "+RPI_I2C_ADDRESS);
  // Join I@c bus as slave with RPI_I2C_ADDRESS 8
  Wire.begin(RPI_I2C_ADDRESS);


  Serial.println("Setting call back for Wire.onReceive");
  Wire.onReceive(receiveData);
  Wire.onRequest(sendData);

  //Setup pin 13 as output and turn LED off
  Serial.println("Setting LED Pin up for Output");
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RELAY_PIN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TEMP_PIN1, INPUT);
  Serial.println("Turning LED off");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

float getVoltage(int pin)
{
  // This function has one input parameter, the analog pin number
  // to read. You might notice that this function does not have
  // "void" in front of it; this is because it returns a floating-
  // point value, which is the true voltage on that pin (0 to 5V).
  return (analogRead(pin) * 0.004882814);
  // This equation converts the 0 to 1023 value that analogRead()
  // returns, into a 0.0 to 5.0 value that is the true voltage
  // being read at that pin.
}


/*
 * MAIN LOOP
 */
void loop() {

  if ( number > 0 ) {
    //Serial.println("Flash Data: "+String(number));
    flash_data(number);
    float voltage, avgVoltage, degreesC, degreesF;
    if (number == 1) {
      digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN1, HIGH);
    } else if (number == 2) {
      digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN1, LOW);
    } else if ( number == 3 ) {
      voltage = getVoltage(TEMP_PIN1);
      //gets and prints the raw data from the lm35
      Serial.print("Voltage: ");
      Serial.print (voltage);
      Serial.println(" ");
      // Now we'll convert the voltage to degrees Celsius.
      // This formula comes from the temperature sensor datasheet:
      degreesC = (voltage - 0.48) * 100.0;
      Serial.print("CELSIUS: ");
      Serial.print(degreesC);
      Serial.println("*C ");
      //converts celsius into fahrenheit 
      degreesF = degreesC * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
      Serial.print("FAHRENHEIT: ");
      Serial.print(degreesF);
      Serial.println("*F");
    } else if ( number == 4 ) {
       displayTime();
    }
    number = 0;
  } else {
    byte pinValue = bitRead(LED_BUILTIN, 3);
    if ( digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN) == HIGH ) {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    }
  }
  delay(SAMPLE_TIME);
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!
THanks

Comment: Could you please show a schematic of your circuit? Do you really want your Arduino to be both a master and a slave on the I2C bus? Why not connect the Pi through Serial?

Answer (score 1):

The onRequest and onReceive callback functions are called from inside an ISR. Thus you cannot use any code in there, that relies on interrupts to work. Serial writes or prints for example will only work, as longs as the buffer is not full (since the actual communication is handled by interrupts). If the buffer is full, the serial code will either block or loose data (depending on the version of the Arduino core. Not blocking in an ISR is a relatively new change). Such things also hapoen with other interrupt driven functions.

Let's take your codes logic particular in the onRequest callcack function. As written above, this is called from an ISR. The Wire library was contacted by the master to send data to it. With this callback the library uis asking you, what to answer the master. During that time, the current transmission (master read, slave send) is already active, but the slave is stalling the transaction, until the data is ready, meaning until you exit the onRequest callback. Now inside the callback you try to initiate another transaxtion on the same I2C bus, now as a master. The same I2C bus, where there is already a transaction going on. That cannot work. The former slave cannot take the control over the bus, since the first master haven't released it yet (as you tried this in the middle of it's transaction. So you are not only using interrupt driven functions in an ISR, you are also trying to reconfigure hardware, that you just got an interrupt from (which is a bad idea, unless you really know, what you are doing). The library has configured the hardware as slave and in the middle of the transaction you try to configure it as master.

I don't know, why you even try to do this. Since you already have the RTC on the same bus as the Pi, why not making the Pi the only master and let it directly poll the RTC? Why do you need the Arduino between them?

If you really really need the multi master setup for whatever reason (though I cannot think of one), you have to do the transactions independent of one another. The Arduino could poll the RTC regularly, when the bus is free, and buffer the results. Then it could send these results to the Pi, when it requests the Arduino to do that.

---

Note: I'm currently not up to date, how good the multi master support in the Wire library is these days. It incorporated the possibility for multi master since a long time, but when I checked last time, the bus arbitration was not implemented (meaning that if 2 masters try to send at the same time, the bus gets stalled). If it is still this way, you shouldn't use multi master with the Wire library.

Comment: Thanks chrisl! Sorry everyone. I realized moments after posting that I am conflicting between the 2 I2C devices in the way I am trying to do this which I think aligns with chrisl's post. DUH! I should be able to make a request to the RTC directly from the RPi via it's address given they are both on the same I2C bus. I will post this definitely once I've tested but I am pretty sure that's what is wrong. Total Bone Head Move.